# Is there a command to extend a guide in Indesign over the entire pasteboard; or limit it to the page?

Tags: adobe-indesign, guides

When I draw guides in InDesign, there are two possible end results: the guide covers the entire pasteboard, or it stops at the page edge.

[image: example of different guide types]

I know that I can control this difference by the location of my cursor when I release my click-drag for creating or editing the guide.

Is there a way to toggle a guide from the one type to the other **without having to click and drag it again**? I find that my click-dragging usually moves the guide by a little, and I like them in the location I put them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85875/discussion-on-question-by-vincent-is-there-a-command-to-extend-a-guide-in-indesi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this JavaScript:

```
app.selection[0].fitToPage ^= true;
```

… with a guide selected, of course.

Comment: You shot faster than me ^^ Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

I am unaware of a command to systematically convert guides between page-only and drawing board guides *without* direct users interaction with the guide itself. That doesn't mean one doesn't exist, merely that I'm completely unaware of such a command.

The only way I know to covert existing guides is to *click them*. As you know, *were* you release makes all the difference.  You can click a page-only guide, drag the mouse outside the page and release, then it's a drawing board guide (or see the hot key below for page-only guides). And vice versa - click a drawing board guide, have the cursor over the page, and release, it becomes a page-only guide.

I am aware this **does not** solve the *"Damn! I moved that 2pts"* issue. Which is annoying to me as well.

When dragging guides, if you are letting go **on the page**, holding <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> when you *release* the guide will make it a drawing board guide, as opposed to a page-only guide. You'll see it extend as soon as you hold <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>. I don't think there's a command when dragging and creating a drawing board guide to restrict it to the page though.

And holding <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key while dragging a guide will rotate the guide 90°, making a horizontal drag create a vertical guide and vice versa.

Comment: That's lots of flowery language :) Thanks, Scott.

Comment: indeed it is :)